# Rmarkdown knit gives pdf with wrong plot. ggplot2 alone renders the right one

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, tukey

The code I am attaching here renders the wrong plot when knitted ("Tk.wrong.png", first plot here). However, if I run it as a standard R code, the rendered plot is the right one ("Tk.right.png", second plot). I find this puzzling. Any hints? Thanks a lot.
Best,
David R
PS: The Tk data.frame can be downloaded here.
https://mycore.core-cloud.net/index.php/s/OKF9dp1tWa0OR1g

[image: Tk.wrong.png][image: Tk.right.png]

This is the Tk data frame
[image]

```
---
```

### title: "Tukey plot help"
author: "DR"
date: "16/10/2020"
output: pdf_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
setwd("~/Documents/IPBS/JN/AB")
library(tidyverse)
input.data <- read.table("input.data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

```
Tk <- rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(TukeyHSD(aov(Score_Avg ~ Manip * Traitement, data = input.data), "Traitement")$Traitement),var = "comp") 
Tk$signif <- sapply(1:nrow(Tk), function (x) between(0,Tk$lwr[x],Tk$upr[x]))
Tk$comp <- as.factor(Tk$comp)
levels(Tk$comp) <- c("Genta-NT", "3T-NT", "G3T-NT", "3T-Genta", "G3T-Genta", "G3T-3T")
```

```
ggplot(Tk, aes(x = diff, y = comp, colour = signif)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = lwr, xmax = upr), width = .1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "darkgreen") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('darkred','darkblue')) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.position = "none")
ggsave("Tk.wrong.png")
```

Comment: Could you please make your example reproducible by adding a snippet of your data? Besides that. In general I would trust the Rmd plot. Why? Because Rmd is build on the notion of reproducibility. Therefore an Rmd renders you code in a fresh and clean R session. If running exactly the same code in a standard R script gives you different results I would suggest to restart your R session and try again.

Comment: Hi Stefan,I tried what oyu suggested, including restarting RStudio etc. Same thing. THe plot I get with ggplot2 is the right one definitely. The one with Rmarkdown is wringn, it seems as it not takin the y axis levels as it should. Here is the data. A hope it is legible.

Comment: The Tk data.frame can be downloaded here. Thanks again. https://mycore.core-cloud.net/index.php/s/OKF9dp1tWa0OR1g

Comment: Hi David. I ran your code (and I mean exactly the same code) both within an Rmd and in a standard R script. And as expected. I got the same plots. However, the plots I got were different from yours. So I had another look. And yep. One issue with your code is that with `levels(Tk$comp) <- c(....)` you are not setting the levels you are overwritting the levels, i.e. the labels change. If I instead use `Tk$comp <- factor(Tk$comp, levels = c("Genta-NT", "3T-NT", "G3T-NT", "3T-Genta", "G3T-Genta", "G3T-3T"))` I finished up with your right plot. Both in the Rmd and in the standard R script.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Stefan, I'll try that out as soon as I can. Best, David

Comment: Hi Stefan, well I sorted it out, but it is very weird. If I run the code as you suggested, I got the right plot. However, if I knit the rmd with that same code, I get an even more strange plot than before (with only one label on y, the others being NA). BUT, and this is the best part, if witihn the rmd I export the Tk data.frame and then I import it back, then the plot is fine. I checked and Tk seems identical before and after import (same summary, same levels...), but rmd does not agree, for reasons that are beyond my comprenhesion. Thanks again for your help. Best.